# Get all pixels different from a color and paint them in other image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have image A with dimension (512, 512, 3).
I want to find all the pixels which != [255,255,255].
Given that pixels, I want to color these coordinates in another image B.
What am I doing wrong?

```
indices = np.where(imgA!= [255,255,255])
imgB[indices] = [0,0,0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This template should get you on the right path:

```
from PIL import image

picture = Image.open(path_to_picture)

width, height = picture.size

for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        current_color = picture.getpixel( (x,y) )
        if current_color[0:3]!=(255,255,255):
            picture.putpixel( (x,y), (***, ***,***) + (current_color[-1],))

picture.save(path_to_new_picture)
```

Note here that `getpixel()` will return a tuple that contains the RGBA values for the given pixel. In this example, I am assuming that you are retaining the alpha value and simply modifying the RGB values of the current pixel.

Answer (score 0):

you need to loop over each pixel in the image.

... `imgA!= [255,255,255]` will always return true, because you are comparing a (512,512,3) nd.array to a (3,) nd.array

Even if your images are not built from numpy matricies, this point still applies. If you run into performance issues, use *cython* for faster for loops.